# Ionic 6 Http Post shows unknown error in normalizedNames for capacitor project

Tags: wordpress, ionic-framework, ionic4, wordpress-rest-api

I am calling my Wordpress REST JSON API in my Ionic Capacitor Project.

But i am getting the error shown in image below.

[Ionic Capacitor HTTP Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5FBN.jpg)

This is my code

```
const httpHeader = { // constant for http headers
  headers : new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  })
};

createComment(comment: Comment): Observable<any> { 
    return this.http.post('https://readymadecode.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments/create,{
    "post":4000,
    "parent":"0",
    "author_name":"chetan",
    "author_email":"chetan@gmail.com",
    "content":"nice good article"
},httpHeader).pipe(map(this.dataExtract),catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }

private dataExtract(res: Response){ // This method extract data from the request response
    const body = res;
    return body || {};
  }

  private errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse){ // Method for error handler
    console.error(error.error instanceof ErrorEvent?`Error message: 
      ${error.error.message}`:`Error status: ${error.error.data.status} Body: ${error.error.message}`);
    return throwError(`${error.error.message}`);
  }
```

When i call the createComment function it shows error see in image above. I have tried enable CORS with cordova-plugins-whitelist but still it shows error.

But this api is working fine in postman. I am using this in postman.

URL: https://www.readymadecode.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments/create
Method: POST
Body: {
"post":4000,
"parent":"0",
"author_name":"chetan",
"author_email":"chetan@gmail.com",
"content":"nice good article"
}

Please help how can i solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

after try all the methods available on google, i able to solve this issue by simply removing the httpHeader from the api.

```
createComment(comment: Comment): Observable<any> { 
    return this.http.post('https://readymadecode.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments/create,{
    "post":4000,
    "parent":"0",
    "author_name":"chetan",
    "author_email":"chetan@gmail.com",
    "content":"nice good article"
},httpHeader).pipe(map(this.dataExtract),catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }
```